# Prestashop Blocklayered: show wrong stock available Products

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I have a Prestashop 1.6.1.3 website for a client which have problem with block layered module v2.2, in the left block the stock availabitlity filter, when clicked is showing wrong products.
I tried to reindex products, attributes, prices, but the problem persist.
Any help would be appreciable

Comment: Unfortunately the `block layered` module has always given problems. I'll suggest to pick up a serious module that filters products :). Sorry

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this issue by adding in blocklayered.php

```
and sa.id_product_attribute = 0 to sql that filters stock
```

In line 1857

```
case 'quantity':
                if (count($selected_filters['quantity']) == 2)
                    break;

                $query_filters_where .= ' AND sa.quantity '.(!$selected_filters['quantity'][0] ? '<=' : '>').' 0 ';
                $query_filters_from .= 'LEFT JOIN `'._DB_PREFIX_.'stock_available` sa ON (sa.id_product = p.id_product '.StockAvailable::addSqlShopRestriction(null, null,  'sa').' and sa.id_product_attribute = 0) ';
            break;
```

Answer (score 0):

Agree with [sarcom](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4519917/sarcom)'s comment the block layered module has always given problems, it uses templates for indexing. Try creating a new template and build all indexes. This solved the issue in older version.

Comment: what do you mean by 'uses templates for indexing'? i think the products and attributes are indexed in the database (specific tables)